# Getting 'import.meta' error when updating blazor app to dotnet 7

Tags: blazor, .net-7.0

I have updated my code from dotnet 6 to dotnet 7. It builds and everything looks fine until i run it. Then i get the error message:
`Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use 'import.meta' outside a module (at dotnet.7.0.0.amub20uvka.js:8:27)`

Any ideas?

Comment: Make sure you don't have any packages using dotnet 6 versions. run `dotnet list package --outdated` (thanks to @StevenTCramer for the tip)

Comment: Had the same error.  After clearing browsing data by using Chrome settings site started functioning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this issue](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/44963) the problem is having some outdated packages as stated by [@Mister Magoo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2658697/mister-magoo). Updating WebAssembly did the trick for me.

Answer (score 8):

1. Update outdated packages
2. Clear cache
3. If you have users and they have old cached files,try adding a query string in the script tag for blazor.webassembly.js in index.html

Example:
src="_framework/blazor.webassembly.js?v=20230301"

Answer (score 3):

Things you can try:

- Check your dotnet version in project.csproj:
  `<TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>`
- Check your versions in project.csproj for:
  `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly` and
  `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.DevServer`
  (**This point solved my problem last time for me**)

Comment: For me, put simply: Run all NuGet updates after switching your project(s) from .NET 6 -> 7